# create widgets in flutter by using loop

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is my code and i want to create a textfield widget at runtime but i have some problems .

1. i can't use int.parse(controller.text)
   2 . when i create the textfields by using manual number i used in for loop, when i write a number in one of them the others get the same value but it is not what i want .
   3 . and i am confuse how should i save them in repository i would be thankful if you guys help me .

```
   for(int  i = 0 ; i <  num.parse(setController.text)    ; i++)
                              ItemTextField(controller: eSetController, themeData: themeData),
```

and there are some images i attached here to explain my question better
i want to get sets number and then create textfield exp if the sets number is 3 i want 3 textfield
and i want to save them in repository to make it editable .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  final List<TextEditingController> textController = <TextEditingController>[];
  final List<Widget> textFields = <Widget>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: editingController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (editingController.value.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      final String stringValue = editingController.value.text;
                      final int count = int.tryParse(stringValue) ?? 0;
                      addTextField(count);
                    } else {}
                  },
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: textFields.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return textFields.isEmpty
                      ? const SizedBox()
                      : Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(child: textFields[index]),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                removeTextField(index);
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                for (int i = 0; i < textController.length; i++) {
                  log("Index: $i - Value: ${textController[i].value.text}");
                }
              },
              child: const Text("Log Value"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addTextField(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      final TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
      textController.add(editingController);
      textFields.add(TextField(controller: editingController));
    }
    setState(() {});
    return;
  }

  void removeTextField(int index) {
    textController.removeAt(index);
    textFields.removeAt(index);
    setState(() {});
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: it was helpful thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First understand you are using `eSetController` controller for all the text fields which is causing issue of same value on every field.

The solution is create a list of object / Map with length exact number you entered `setController` controller e.g number is 2 then list should look like

```
List controllers =  [ 
  {"input_text":""},
  {"input_text":""},
]
```

Now you will iterate the list and create 2 fields and in `onChange` method pass the value in the correct index of list controller this is how you will get unique values for each field.